# audio conference program using windows mobile and .net framework

Tags: .net, voip, voice, lan, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm trying to develop an application that must run on a set of windows mobile 6.5 phone.

The phones are all connected in a **local LAN** using TCP/Ip and each of them has a fixed IP number but they must not connect to internet !

The goal of the application is to **send and receive audio calls** knowing the Ip number of the destination phone.

So.... i figured out some possible solutions:

1. realize from scratch a client server for voice application for windows mobile
2. find a good control or an easy to use framework
3. just give up :)

Any suggestion?

Thansk everybody

Answer (score 0):

You will want a Media Server capable of doing conferencing.  Asterisk or Freeswitch are two good open source media servers that support conferencing.

Are you creating your own Window Mobile VOIP application?  If so, in your client application you will need to use a SIP client library.  There are a couple of open source SIP stacks available (e.g. pjsip, and others).

Alternatively, you could try installing Fring or Skype for Windows Mobile 6.5 and see if they allow you to place SIP: calls.  If they do, then all you need to do is install your Media Server (mentioned above) on your network.

For a full list of VoIP servers and client-side stacks see here:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Open+Source+VOIP+Software